# IIF(IsNothing(Fields!field.value), "", Fields!.value.ToString)) generates error

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

SQL Server 2005 reporting services.

I want to using the following in a report text box:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Certification.Value), "", 
    "Certs: " + Fields!Certification.Value.ToString() )
```

But because both sides (T/F) are evaluated, I get an error on the report when the field is null. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5):

Use below expression instead

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Certification.Value),nothing,"Certs: " & CStr(Fields!Certification.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is Certification Field a Calculated field or Database field?

if it is Calculated Field then check again your statement.

Cause I do not have to use 'IIF' even when the record contains null value, just Fields!Certification.Value on textbox

Comment: It's a DB field result. Either a string value or NULL. The above answers worked. I didn't think you could do CStr(NULL). I also found another way around. I created a hidden string parameter, Allowed NULL & Blank values. Available Values: from Query - I picked the ValueField. Default Values: From Query - I picked the Value Field & used: =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Certification.Value), "", "Certs: " + Parameters!certs_string.Value) in the TextBox Expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around this situation would be to do an ISNULL(Certification,'') in the SQL Query.  This is  assuming of course that you are querying SQL Server.

```
SELECT ISNULL(Certification,'') as Certification 
FROM YourTableName
```

This way any NULL's appearing in the result-set will be removed.